# Haskell Pascal's triangle

Tags: haskell

I have to create a recursive function that takes in two numbers (n and k) and gives back their binomial coefficient.

I have to use pascal :: Int -> Int -> Int

I honestly don't understand where it went wrong, thanks for the help!

```
pascal :: Int -> Int -> Int
pascal n k
      | k == 0 = 1
      | n == n = 1
      | k > n  = 0
      | otherwise = pascal(n-1)(k-1) + pascal(n-1) + k
```

The following error is:

```
main.hs:7:40: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Int -> Int’
    • Probable cause: ‘pascal’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘pascal (n - 1)’
      In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely
        ‘pascal (n - 1) (k - 1) + pascal (n - 1)’
      In the expression: pascal (n - 1) (k - 1) + pascal (n - 1) + k
  |
7 |       | otherwise = pascal(n-1)(k-1) + pascal(n-1) + k
  |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
<interactive>:3:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: main
    • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the exception says, `pascal (n-1)` does not make much sense, since that is a function `Int -> Int`, so you can not add `pascal (n-1) (k-1)` and `pascal (n-1)` together.

You thus need to pass an extra parameter. For example:

```
pascal :: Int -> Int -> Int
pascal _ 0 = 1
pascal n k
      | k == n = 1
      | k > n = 0
      | otherwise = pascal (n-1) (k-1) + pascal (n-1) k
```

Note that the condition `n == n` is always true, you probably want to say `n == k`?